# How do I recover the Dolphin Sonar icon?

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, dolphin-browser

In my application list, Dolphin Sonar/Sonar is not one of the icons.  I've "peeled off"/deleted all of the Dolphin Sonar icons by mistake, and I want it to be on my home screen.  I use it very often.  Where might I find the icon?  Do I need to reinstall Dolphin?

Comment: I think we need more information. What version of the OS are you running? Are you looking in the "Downloaded" section of the app drawer? If so, it means you've uninstalled the app. To be sure, check `Settings | Applications` to see if it's listed there.

Comment: @AlEverett I received a response from Dolphin HQ's support staff stating that this is currently not possible (at least not on my phone but more likely at all), and they plan to fix this in an upcoming patch.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Please put this as answer and mark the question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Dolphin for Android phone faqs](http://dolphin-browser.com/dolphin-for-android-phone-faqs/), you can manually create a shortcut to the home screen:

> How do I create a shortcut for Dolphin Sonar to the home screen manually?
>
> Please click Menu> More> Settings> Gesture & Sonar > Sonar Settings> Create Shortcut.